# Packages in LANDSCAPE not loading (ERROR : OOPS-96c7199182fb5d5d42c4c3ae106c573d)

Tags: landscape

I just recently installed landscape server and i added a client machine.

When i go to the GUI on the server and wanted to explore packages for that specific client machine it says "System error" with this code "**OOPS ID: ['OOPS-96c7199182fb5d5d42c4c3ae106c573d']**"

Anyone can help me to proceed please?

Best regards